# Data validation using regex MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using regex filter to validate date input on the form in MVC3

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9]{3}( [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)?",ErrorMessage="Incorrect Format")] 
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

Very very strange case: value `01.01.2012 00:00` doesn't satisfy the regex , but when entering value `01.01.2012 10:00` modelstate is valid. I've checked my regex using this http://regexpal.com/ and the value is fine.

Does anybody have any suggestions why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh.... I found the problem myself. I don't know how, but after submitting form, the value `01.01.2012 00:00` was transformed to `01.01.2012 0:00`, so it doesn't satisfy the regex. Well, the regex seemed to be like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.[0-2][0-9]{3}( ([0-2])?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)?",ErrorMessage="Incorrect Format")]
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.